# Width 100% footer with multiple elements that are positioned absolutely doesn't shift with the rest of the layout when window is reduced in width

Tags: html, css, css-position

This is how the site looks with the window in full size:

This is how the site looks with the window reduced in width:

You'll notice that as soon as the window gets reduced in width enough to touch the left edge of the road, the entire footer section (i.e. road, black box, rocks on ground) stops shifting over with the rest of the layout and stays in place.

Ideally, I'd like the footer to shift with the rest of the layout so the black box in the footer matches the grid of the three boxes above it, like this:

I have tried fixing this for a few hours and I figured I could use some help. If someone out there has the patience to help me with this, I'd truly appreciate it.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Unfortunately, the site is still in maintenance mode so I can't give a live demo. I wish I could. Sorry.

Comment: Put the code into http://jsfiddle.net and use absolute paths to the images on your server. That way we can see the issue happening.

Comment: To be fair, it's extremely hard for us to sift through your *entire* html/css to figure out the problem, without any demo to even play with. If you provide a demo, we can simply edit the code in developer tools.

Comment: I added the live demo to jsfiddle. I added it to the original post. Sorry about that guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem in your this image

http://yourdailylaughz.com/wp-content/themes/ydl/images/footer.png

you should crop this image in 2 different slice 1 slice for bridge bg and second for content bg your problem will be solved..